# Powershell to restart a service running longer than

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that will:

- Restart a service if it has been running more than 1 hour
- Leave it alone if less than 1 hour
- Start it if it's in the `stopped` state.

I currently have the following below but when it comes to adding extra variables and `if` statements I'm terrible. This script works very well, but I can't get it to restart, only start/stop seem to work.

```
Get-Service "Print Spooler" | 
    Where StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60) |
    Stop-Service
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a variable for this:

```
# for debugging
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*Service:Verbose'] = $true

$svc = Get-Service -Name Spooler

if ($svc.Status -eq 'stopped') {
    $svc | Start-Service
} elseif ($svc.StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)) {
    $svc | Stop-Service -PassThru | Start-Service
} else {
    'Print Spooler is running and StartTime is within the past hour!'
}

# other logic goes here
```

Comment: You might want to tweak your logic. The OP wants the service to start if it is stopped regardless of start time.

Comment: @EBGreen In their requirement, it says leave it alone if it's been stopped for less than an hour, but I may have misinterpreted that as the question was kind of convoluted.

Comment: Oh, I read that as restart the service if it has been running more than an hour, do nothing to the service if it has been running less than an hour, start the service if it is ever in a stopped state. Entirely possible I read it wrong too.

Comment: EBGreen you have it correct. If the service is running and under an hour leave it alone, if it's not running then run it, and it it's been running over an hour restart it.

Answer (score 0):

`StartTime` doesn't appear to be a property of the ServiceController class that `Get-Service` returns on my system.  Neither is the service's process ID, absurdly enough.  That's infuriatingly poor design, but so it goes.  So, I'd use CIM/WMI to get the process ID to determine when the service started.

```
$Service = Get-Service "Print Spooler"
$ServiceStartTime = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name = '$($Service.Name)'" -Property ProcessId | ForEach-Object { Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId }).StartTime

# If services has been running for an hour, stop it
if (($Service.Status -eq 'Running') -and ($ServiceStartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1))) {
    Stop-Service $Service
}

# If service isn't running, start it
if ($Service.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
    Start-Service $Service 
}
```